# chromium sqlite load_extension not possible

Tags: sqlite, chromium

Maybe someone has chromium build experience and can help further:

Dynamic module loading with chromium sqlite seems to be not possible.

Imagine you want to load the [spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) sqlite extension via javascript.

What I did:

```
    db = window.openDatabase("test.sqlite", 1, "test.sqlite", 10000000);  
    db.transaction(function(tx, myArray) {
     tx.executeSql("select load_extension('/home/user/tmp/libspatialite.so');", [], function(tx, result) {
        console.log("load_extension spatialite");
    },
      function(tx, err) { console.log(err);}
    );
    });
```

But that ends in "could not prepare statement (1 not authorized to use function: load_extension)".

However, I fetched chromium-24.0.1290.0-1.39.1.x86_64.rpm and tried to build chromium with load module extension enabled, without success.

What I did:

- extendend /chromium/src/third_party/sqlite/sqlite.gyp with:

  ```
  'SQLITE_OMIT_AUTHORIZATION',
  ```
- extendend /chromium/src/third_party/sqlite/google_generate_amalgamation.sh with:

  ```
      ../configure --enable-load-extension=yes
  ```

After spending some hours of failing, I made a feature request chromium bug tracker ([web database (sqlite) load_extension is not allowed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160049)). I guess this feature request will not even be recognized by the developers, due to their workload.